# Vb.Net HtmlElement DropList item InvokeMember("click") Does Nothing

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

All.

Scenario:
After successfully logging onto a web page there is a droplist of items. I'm trying to click the first item within that list which should change the bottom contents. I've tried various methods without success. It's not that I'm returning an error, it's simply just not doing anything.

```
    Dim AllElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each WebPageElement As HtmlElement In AllElements

        If WebPageElement.Id = Nothing Then

        Else
            If WebPageElement.Id = "TheElementID" Then
                WebPageElement.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Again, I know the ID and the above hits that click event... but it's not actually going anywhere. It doesn't generate an error.

The more direct approach:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("TheElementID").InvokeMember("click")
```

Also doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't do anything.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Need more info. I can assume the top code block is VB and the bottom code block is JavaScript so I think you're close but what event is calling the second block? Is this in a timer or something so it can be called after the page is rendered to the user?  Why not do it all in VB. Are you using some update panels that are refreshed in your click event or something?  Need more to the story to help.

Comment: They're both VB and the code is interchangeable. This event can take place any time after the web page has finished loading. So, for sake of examples let's say it's within it's own button click.

Comment: Also, the WebBrowser control is receiving the command. It's exactly that, a little web page built into the form and behaves like a web page would if it were in IE, Firefox or Chrome.